# Interfacing A71CH with I2C

Tags: stm32, i2c, stm32f4

I'm trying to interface the following chip with STM32F4
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/supporting-information/AN12207.pdf

I'm currently trying to transmit a repeated start using hal sequential transmission with an interrupt but it doesn't work at all, I get NAK.

Would someone give me insights how to interface it and which HAL functions should I use?

```
unsigned int axI2CWriteRead(unsigned char bus_unused_param, unsigned char addr,
                            unsigned char *pTx, unsigned short txLen,
                            unsigned char *pRx, unsigned short *pRxLen)
{
    extern I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c3;
    bool recv_length = false;
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status;

    *pRxLen = 0;
    memset(pRx, 0, 2);
    uint8_t rxData[255] = {0};

    status = HAL_I2C_Master_Sequential_Transmit_IT(&hi2c3, 0x90, pTx, txLen, I2C_FIRST_FRAME);

    if (status != HAL_OK)
        return I2C_FAILED;

    while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c3) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
        ;

    readblock = true;
    readblock_length = 0;
    status = HAL_I2C_Master_Sequential_Receive_IT(&hi2c3, 0x90, rxData, 255, I2C_LAST_FRAME);

    if (status != HAL_OK)
        return I2C_FAILED;
    while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c3) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
        ;
    readblock = false;
    readblock_length = 0;


    *pRxLen = rxData[0] + 1;

    memcpy(pRx, rxData, *pRxLen);

    return I2C_OK;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code. Has the chip been recognized yet?

Comment: @LongPham I have added code. What do you mean by recognized ?